# How to open first accordion panel on page load?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to open the first accordion panel on page load, right now they are all collapsed on load. Here is my code:

```
$.fn.myAccordion = function(custConf) {

    var config = jQuery.extend({
        button: "accordionButton",
        buttonOpen: "accordionButtonSelected",
        slideDuration: "normal",
        hideContent: "accordionContent"
    }, custConf);

    // SET UP INDIVIDUAL ACCORDIONS FOR EACH MATCH IN THIS jQuery
    this.each(function(index, element) {
        var currentAccordion = null;
        $(element).find("div." + config.button).click(function() {
            if (currentAccordion) {
                $(currentAccordion).next().slideUp(config.slideDuration);
                $(currentAccordion).removeClass().addClass(config.button);
            }
            if (this == currentAccordion) {
                currentAccordion = null;
                return;
            }
            currentAccordion = this;
            $(currentAccordion).next().slideDown(config.slideDuration);
            $(currentAccordion).removeClass().addClass(config.buttonOpen);
        });
    });

    //HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD
    $("div." + config.hideContent).hide();

    return this;
};
```

Comment: you can try finding and clicking the first accordion button: `$("div."+config.button).first().click();` on page load

Comment: Added the answer so you can mark this as solved

Answer (score 3):

**Note : I Have considered Dynamically Created Accordion.**

Find your first accordion from div in following way

$('.theDivHoldingAccordion').find('.ClassOfYourAccordion:first').trigger('onclick');

Just show the div in which you are loading data on Accordion's click even.
    $('.DivInWhichYouAreLoadingDataOnAccordionClick').find('.accordion-section-
    content1:first').show();

Answer (score 1):

Click the first button of the accordion after it hides the content.

```
  ...
  $("div." + config.hideContent).hide();

  $("div."+config.button).first().click();

  return this;
};
```